# How to build with Maven and deploy to Wildfly 9 in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, wildfly

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.3.2 as my IDE, and I would like to create a run/debug configuration that builds my Java 8 app with Maven, and deploys it to a local Wildfly 9.0.1 standalone server.

So far I have managed to create a configuration that deploys a .war from external source to the Wildfly with debugging, and it works as intended. The external source points to a .war that i manually build with Maven through a command line. 
This fulfills my needs, but I would like to include the maven build in my run/debug configuration, to simplify the process.

I need to pass some arguments to my mvn install command.

How can I include the Maven build with arguments in my run/debug configuration in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Run->Edit Configurations->Add->Maven. Set up maven configuration in intellij to build your project. Then edit the run/debug configs to run this maven config before launch

Answer (score 2):

I ended up adding an execution of a Maven goal to the run/debug configuration. Under the "server" tab, I added the Maven goal, which lets me execute my Maven command in a specified directory, to the "before launch" list. I removed the IntelliJ "build" from the list.

The deployment is still an external source pointing to the .war which is now build as part of the configuration.

This works for me, but if anyone has a better approach, feel free to add it.